# Webpack installation command not having bundle.js appear

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I keep getting

when I try to link two of my scripts together when I put 'webpack app.js bundle.j' in the command line

bash: /usr/local/bin/webpack: No such file or directory
Jaffers-MacBook-Pro:test JafferSyed$

I am not sure what is the problem

HTML

```
  <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS (app.js)

```
    var math = require('./math.js');
```

I am trying to require the math.js in the /node_modules/mathjs

here is what my node modules folder looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujb78.png)

Here is what my files list looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfthw.png)

I am presumed to believe that a bundle.js file should appear when I am to add 'webpack app.js bundle.js' on the command line of my terminal

I am not sure as to why there it says no such file or directory

Comment: Please include your code/input/output as text in your question, it makes it easier for people to take the time to help you.

Comment: @robinsax Hello, thank you for answering I did not have that much code to begin with I was trying to solve the problem of fixing the required is not defined issue I was having with webpack

Comment: @robinsax but I did edit the question to about all the information that I have

Comment: The `./` means import a file relative to app.js To import a node module, reference it by the module name. `var math = require('mathjs');`

Comment: @AndyRay Hello, I have tried editing it to         var math = require('mathjs'); and it still returns that the file or directory is not found